# how to add textures to the overlay of jquery ui modal dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I use jquery ui modal dialog without any problem. My Q is that is it possible to add a texture or imag to the dark and disabling layer behind the modal dialog?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! By editting the url of `background` property of the block `.ui-widget-overlay` in the `jquery-ui.css` file:

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
    position:absolute;
    background: #aaaaaa url("whatever you want") 50% 50% repeat-x;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=70);
}
```

Comment: you should add your own CSS sheet that overrides jQuery's rather than editing theirs.

Comment: you should be able to do it just be writing a new style sheet including just the above, and including it _after_ the jQuery UI .css file.  You won't even need to include the properties that are unchanged - just the ones you want to have different values.

Comment: Got it. I thought that there should be a more handy trick for that. OK, thanks